# In 'plotly', how to change frame text font (size/angle etc.)

Tags: r, plotly

In 'plotly', how to change frame text font (size/angle etc.) .Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
p <- dplyr::starwars %>% ggplot(aes(x=height,y=mass,frame=skin_color))+
  geom_point()

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example of possible customization:

```r
ggplotly(p) %>% 
  animation_slider(
    font = list(color = "red", size = 12, family = "sans serif"),
    tickcolor = "red"
  )
```

unfortunately I was unable to rotate the text.
For more information, see the official guide:

https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/